# Flask-Session Redis connecting to wrong host on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, redis

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from redis import Redis

app = Flask(__name__)

SESSION_TYPE='redis'
SESSION_REDIS = Redis(host='xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com', port=6379, db=0)
Session(app)
```

This works fine when running on localhost, but on AWS I get the following every time I try and load a page:

```
ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

The `localhost` bit doesn't make any sense. Adding a `print SESSION_REDIS` gives:

`Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=xxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com,port=6379,db=0>>>`

I can reach my ElastiCache redis instance from my EC2 instance via `redis-cli`

```
$ redis-cli -h xxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com ping
PONG
```

Unsure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually applying any of your configurations to Flask, you're simply setting a variable. In order for a setting to be applied to flask (and any extension), you'll need to set the value in the application's configuration object (which is essentially just a `dict`).

You can either set the values within the `Flask.config` object directly

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = Redis(host='xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com', port=6379, db=0)

Session(app)
```

Alternately, if you want to use the variables that you have defined in this file, you can do:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

SESSION_TYPE='redis'
SESSION_REDIS = Redis(host='xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com', port=6379, db=0)

app.config.from_object(__name__)

Session(app)
```

See more information on [configuring Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/) to see all of the different ways that you can set these configuration options.

Comment: Ah thanks. in my real code, I have all my configs in a cfg file loaded with `from_pyfile`. All except my `SESSION_REDIS` connection string. Makes sense now why it was using the default localhost connection.